# C++11: struct timeval

Tags: c++, c++11

I was told to not include the C headers like `<stdio.h>` in a c++ program, but to use `<cstdio>` etc. instead. How do I get `struct timeval` without including `<sys/time.h>`?

Alternative question, is there any C++11 alternative to using select/poll (on a POSIX system)?

Comment: I suggest you use `<chrono>` in C++

Comment: Are you asking about `struct timeval`, or about `select`/`poll`? These are completely different questions.

Comment: @DyP: I assume he is talking about `<ctime>`, which provides `std::time(std::time_t *)`, borrowed from standard C.

Comment: @DyP I meant C++ only has versions of standard C library headers (plus its own). It does not have C++ versions of the POSIX headers.

Comment: @Nemo: I essentially want to know how to idiomatically block on multiple fds until one becomes ready in C++11. `struct timeval` and `select` are related because `struct timeval` is an argument to `select`.

Comment: @JoSo - Always ask the question corresponding to what you are actually trying to do. The way you have phrased this, you will get responses like "use `<ctime>`" or "use `<chrono>`", which are correct if what you want is to measure time. What you really mean is "how do I do `select()` portably", which none of these responses is even attempting to answer because it is not what you asked.

Comment: @Nemo: nevermind, it seems the question was ok, as you can see from the answers, and I definitely learned a bit. I also feel better now simply using `select()`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `<cstdio>` and similar are C++ variants for the C standard library. `<sys/time.h>` is not part of the C standard library at all (it is part of the POSIX interface for certan OS's), so there is no such thing as a C++ specific `sys/ctime`, so no, you just have to use the same header-file as in C.

The main reason for having a C style and C++ style header is to apply the `extern "C"` to the functions declared in the headerfile. In some systems, it may be required to wrap the function like this:

```
 extern "C" {
 #include <sys/time.h>
 }
```

but in my Linux system, it does that in the standard `<sys/time.h>` file.

Comment: Should you include the POSIX headers in a `extern "C" { /*...*/ }` linkage specification?

Comment: @DyP: It seems like the Linux version on my machine has a `__BEGIN_DECLS` which is as appropriate set to `extern "C" {` (and an `__END_DECLS` to match at the other end. Edit being made...

Comment: @DyP: Doh! Some days I wonder how I manage to type anything... ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `<cstdio>` is a C++ variants of the C library `<stdio.h>`. The difference is that the C versions are defined in the global namespace.

You can see a list of those headers here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/

`<sys/time.h>` is not a part of the standard library so there is no equivalent in C++. You just have to use it like in C.